# React-Saga - how to make nested generators work

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I upgraded from old redux saga to the latest version and the following stopped working.

```
function* loadAlbumPhoto({ entity }, entityId) {
      try {
        const { accessToken: at } = yield select(state => state.user.info);

        let {
          data: { data: albums }
        } = yield call(API.loadAlbumByEntityId, { entityName: entity, entityId, type: PHOTO });

        if (!albums.length) {
          const options = {
            entityId,
            entityName: entity,
            title:      PHOTO,
            type:       PHOTO
          };
          yield call(API.createAlbum, options);
          ({ data: { data: albums } } = yield call(API.loadAlbumByEntityId, { entityName: entity, entityId, type: PHOTO }));
        }

        const [album] = albums;

        const { data: { data: photos } } = yield call(API.loadPhotosByAlbumId, album.id);
        return yield photos.map(function* (photo) {
          const src = yield getPhotoUrl(photo.uploadData.path, at);

          return {
            src,
            uploadId: photo.uploadId,
            photoId:  photo.id
          };
        });
      } catch (err) {

        console.log(err);

        return [];
      }
    }


function* getPhotoUrl(path, at) {
  try {
    const userPhoto = yield API.userPhoto(path, at);
    return userPhoto;
  } catch (err) {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    console.log(err);
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
  }
  return "";
}
```

As you can see i am trying to return array from loadAlbumPhoto but my problem is that i need to call getPhotoUrl function which is also a generator function.

The problem is that the result of loadAlbumPhoto is Array of generators and not Array of values. It happened since my upgrade to the last version of redux and redux saga.

Already tried to use `yield*` but not working or i don't know how to use it.
[yield*](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a bit of refactoring of the anonymous generator and then convert your `yield` to use `all`: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects---parallel-effects

```
function* getPhotoDetails(photo) {
  const src = yield getPhotoUrl(photo.uploadData.path, at);
  return {
    src,
    uploadId: photo.uploadId,
    photoId:  photo.id
  };
}

function* loadAlbumPhoto({ entity }, entityId) {
    // similar up to yield photos.map...
    return yield all(photos.map(photo => call(getPhotoDetails, photo)));
    // similar after
}
```